# BeautifulSoup - check if elements have specific class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How would i check if there are specific classes (`my_class1` or `my_class2`) in `soup`? Right now im using:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for node in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':re.compile("my_class1")}):
    print(node)
```

I know I can use solve it using `lxml`, but im looking for BS solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
for node in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": re.compile(r'my_class(1|2)')}):
    print(node)
```